# JQuery cancel entered text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, dom-events

When typing into a `<input type="text">` field I would like to precheck every entered value before it appears on the screen. E.g. if the user enters any non numeric value, nothing will happen and only if he enters a numeric value the field will change.

Which is the right event to use `keydown()`, `keyup()` or is there something better? How do I cancel the current change of the text field without having to remember the old value and manually resetting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind to the `keypress` event and then check the character represented by the `which` property of the event object. If it isn't a number you can use `preventDefault` to prevent the default behaviour of writing the character to the element:

```
$("#someInput").keypress(function(e) {
    if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XGPt9/10/).